FileManager copy item from Google Drive using UIDocumentBrowserViewController
I'm using UIDocumentBrowserViewController to let the user pick a file from iCloud, but I also want to handle documents from Google Drive, Dropbox etc.
The user selects the file, the file is copied to the temporary dictionary, I read the content of the file and display it in the app.
func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIDocumentBrowserViewController {
    let viewController = UIDocumentBrowserViewController(forOpening: configuration.types)
    viewController.allowsPickingMultipleItems = configuration.allowsPickingMultipleItems
    viewController.allowsDocumentCreation = false
    viewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    return viewController
}

Then I implement didPickDocumentsAt delegate:
func documentBrowser(_ controller: UIDocumentBrowserViewController, didPickDocumentsAt documentURLs: [URL]) {
    var copiedURLs: [URL] = []

    for url in documentURLs {
        guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
            continue
        }
        defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

        let destinationUrl = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)

        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationUrl)
            }
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: destinationUrl)
            copiedURLs.append(destinationUrl)
        } catch {

        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.parent.documentsURLs = copiedURLs
        self.parent.isPresented = false
    }
}

Things work like a charm for iCloud content... but not for Google Drive or other sources. This is the error I receive:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “import.xlsx” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/DADF0147-...-0CA3F44EFE1C/File Provider Storage/38101502/1TK...e/import.xlsx, NSUnderlyingError=0x301ee1dd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Is there something I miss regarding using UIDocumentBrowserViewController for other sources?
Related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130790
